# XSLT autocomplete with NetBeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans

I remember then it was XSLT support in NetBeans 6. And now I am using NetBeans 6.8 and still can't find such plugin. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

tools->plugins->settings add http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.8/uc/m1/dev/catalog.xml
then install SOA