# Netbeans 6.9 + XSL autocomplete

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, xslt-tools

Theres some way to do Netbeans 6.9.1 autocomplete XSL tags?

Comment: It means disfunction of plugin for XML... I really want to know, how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

A [feature request](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=134727) has been raised for this but without a solution.

This question has also been asked before, albeit for Netbeans v6.8 - [XSLT autocomplete with NetBeans 6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616258/xslt-autocomplete-with-netbeans-6-8)

The only information I could find is for Netbeans v6.5 so I do not know if it will still work with v6.9 but you could try that if you have not done so already - see [Code completion for XSLT 2.0 in NetBeans 6.5](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/11/code-completion-for-xslt-20-in-netbeans.html) or [XSLT Code completion](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/XSLT-Code-completion-td2937779.html#a2937780)

Hope this helps.